# How to get ButtonGroup of JRadioButton

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox, jradiobutton

In a project, I added ItemListener to a group of JcheckBox and JRadioButtons.

And I want that when a user click on already selected JRadioButton, it gets deselected.

For this only method I know is getting Corresponding ButtonGroup and then calling clearSelection() method. 
But in itemStateChanged() method I have JtoggleButton option=(JtoggleButton)event.getSource();

So option refers to either JRadioButton or JcheckBox. I have searched but I cannot able to find a method to get ButtonGroup for a JRadioButton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `getSource` and check with `instanceof`. If it is a `JRadioButton` cast it to `JRadioButton` and set `selected` to false. Same thing for `JCheckBox`

```
if(event.getSource instanceof JRadioButton){

 JRadioButton  btn=(JRadioButton)    event.getSource();
    btn.setSelected=false;
}
else if (event.getSource instanceof JCheckBox){

  JCheckBox chb=  (JCheckBox)    event.getSource();
    chb.setSelected=false;
}
```

**IF you want to deselect already selected one you can add a condition like below**

```
if(event.getSource instanceof JRadioButton){

  JRadioButton  btn=(JRadioButton)    event.getSource();
  if(btn.isSelected())
     btn.setSelected=false;
}
else if (event.getSource instanceof JCheckBox){   
  JCheckBox chb=  (JCheckBox)    event.getSource();
  if(chb.isSelected())
     chb.setSelected=false;
}
```